# How to call methods of different classes passed as parameter type?

Tags: java, generics

How would I do something like this? Ignore the syntax errors.

```
//some class
class A {
    //some func
    func(){
    
    }
}

class B {
    func2(){
    }
}

//Generic Class that can take type A or B
class generic<T> {
    func3(T){
        //How to do this?
        T.func();
        T.func2();
    }
}
```

I really don't understand Generics. Sorry if it sounds ridiculous.

Comment: Why do you use generics for this? You could simply have two overloads for `func3`: `func3(A a)` and `func3(B b)`.

Comment: Thats my point...what is the difference between method overloading and generics? When should we use generics? only for Integer, Double, String etc? Really dont understand Generics...read the oracle docs..

Comment: I'll only give you one difference (read on generics as the actual answer is too long): when you overload `func3` with `A` and `B` as parameter types, your callers know about `A` and `B` and they can only use those two. When `generic` is a generic class and `func3` takes the generic type parameter `T`, your callers get to choose whatever they want to use as argument for `T`, and you don't know what `T` is, which makes the compiler prevent you from invoking arbitrary methods on `T` objects. But you can use `T extends ...` if `A` and `B` are related and you're calling a common method.

Answer (score 0):

You use generic to abstract the "shape" of class you can work on without caring about the actual implementation classes.

You should create a common interface

```
interface Common {
  void doWork();
}

//some class
class A implements Common {
    void doWork() {
      func();
    }

    //some func
    func(){
    
    }
}

class B implements Common {
    void doWork() {
      func2();
    }

    func2(){
    }
}

//Generic Class that can take type A or B
class generic<T extends Common> {
    func3(T task){
        task.doWork();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So pretty much you want to have a class that takes another Util class(or whatever it does) And calls some standard(generic) method on it. What i would do is Create an interface with the method;

```java
public interface ExampleInterface {
   void methodToCall();
}
```

Then you have your class that takes a implementation of that Interface;

```java
public class OtherExampleClass<T extends ExampleInterface> {
    public void call(T caller){
       caller.methodToCall();
    }
}
```

For the record, So far this really doesnt need to be genericized at all, I would really only do this if your Class 'A' and 'B' have some specific return type based on which one you provide when instantiated your 'Generic' class.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this point " I would really only do this if your Class 'A' and 'B' have some specific return type based on which one you provide when instantiated your 'Generic' class."

Comment: What is a class return type?